# Android Gradle export failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am having trouble migrating my eclipse project to Android Studio. I followed the instcutions on this page http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

When I type gradle at the command line I get this error:

- Where:
  Settings file 'C:\Users\Joshua\Development\workspace\settings.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'workspace'.

  > A path must be specified!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.1 secs

What path do you think it wants? And where does it want it?

Comment: it looks like mine says that "build file : null" when i debug gradle but I don't understand why it would say that as build.gradle is indeed in the project dir. I'm running gradle from the command line btw

Comment: i got it to go further if you remove the absolute paths that were put into the include of the settings.gradle file. I'm still having problems with path resolution though, seems like most of the problems have to do with win/unix

Answer (score 4):

So in my case I had a multi-project environment, what I had to do to get it working was to remove the absolute paths from the settings.gradle file in the root directory (dir containing all of the projects) and then in the build.gradle i had to remove the absolute directories for the compile statments and make sure that i used :{project_name} instead of ../{poject_name}

I realise that my situation was a bit different but if you download gradle and use the --debug switch you should be able to find which files have the problems and it's most likely a path problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing your lop-level build.gradle file. [Here is a setup explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508345/android-gradle-module-dependancies/18374871#18374871)
If this is not your issue, please provide your settings.gradle file and top-level build.gradle file.