# Android Studio - migrating projects from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to migrate my Android projects from eclipse to Android Studio.  I followed the instructions here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html after installing the latest Android Studio and Gradle.  When I try to import the main project I get this error:

```
Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\gradle-1.6'.
Settings file 'C:\P4\java\EIQBlackberry\workspace\settings.gradle' line: 1
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'workspace'.
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'workspace'.
A path must be specified!
```

This is what my `settings.gradle` looks like:

```
include ':C::P4:java:EIQBlackberry:workspace:ActionBarSherlock4'
include ':C::P4:java:EIQBlackberry:workspace:ViewPagerIndicatorSherlock'
... (a few more include lines just like the above for the other projects)
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: added full log with stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\gradle-1.6'.
Settings file 'C:\P4\java\EIQBlackberry\workspace\settings.gradle' line: 1
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'workspace'.
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'workspace'.
A path must be specified!
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    ... 20 more
2013-06-06 13:16:37,663 [  59324]   WARN - ctExternalProjectImportBuilder - org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\gradle-1.6'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConnection$2.run(DefaultAsyncConnection.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:46)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(ProjectResolver.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$ProjectResolverFunctionFactory$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:153)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$ProjectResolverFunctionFactory$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:149)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.ExternalSystemFacadeImpl$1.invoke(ExternalSystemFacadeImpl.java:158)
    at $Proxy3.resolveProjectInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.LocationAwareException: Settings file 'C:\P4\java\EIQBlackberry\workspace\settings.gradle' line: 1
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'workspace'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:85)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:108)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating settings 'workspace'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:59)
    at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.loadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:102)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(SettingsHandler.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: A path must be specified!
    at org.gradle.util.Path.isAbsolutePath(Path.java:163)
    at org.gradle.util.Path.absolutePath(Path.java:148)
    at org.gradle.util.Path.resolve(Path.java:144)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor.absolutePath(DefaultProjectDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor.path(DefaultProjectDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor.<init>(DefaultProjectDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BaseSettings.createProjectDescriptor(BaseSettings.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BaseSettings.include(BaseSettings.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:804)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1096)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1049)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at settings_b41igkftpgg6afk3j3kbc00me.run(C:\P4\java\EIQBlackberry\workspace\settings.gradle:1)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: also, ignore the "blackberry" in the name, something i don't have the power to change, this is in fact an android project

Answer (score 5):

There's a bug on windows when exporting project with several modules. We are fixing this now, and we'll release a fix ASAP.

Comment: I have this problem as well... Care to give us an estimated release date please ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. This solved it for me : [Android Gradle export failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886954/android-gradle-export-failed)

So basically, edit your settings.gradle and build.gradle files and use a relative path instead of an absolute path. (E.g. ':actionbarsherlock' instead of ':C:\projects\actionbarsherlock' )

Comment: I'm new to gradle, are the paths supposed to have : instead of \ like what I've got? (include ':C::P4:java:EIQBlackberry:workspace:ActionBarSherlock4')