# Android Gradle module dependancies

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem while building a project on Android using Gradle.

I have a project structure as following:

```
root
 settings.gradle
 build.gradle

   - Project 1 (android studio "module")
      build.gradle

   - Project 2 (android studio "module")
      build.gradle
```

If I select the project 1 and compile, it works
If I select the project 2 and compile, it works as well

Now, I would like to have a dependancy from the project 2 on the project 1 to reuse some of my application logic.

Following the doc I try to add in the project 2 build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Project1')
}
```

but it doesn't work.

My settings.gradle contains:

```
include ':Project1', ':Project2'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the plugin **android-library** in your library project (project1) :

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 17
}
```

Link to the [Gradle documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Creating-a-Library-Project) about making library projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse some logic from Project1 you should create a library project, Project3-lib. Move your reusable code to this new project and let Project1 and Project2 depend on it.

This is how you can do it:

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':Project3-lib', ':Project1', ':Project2'
```

In your **Project1** and **Project2** you add your new lib project

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Project3-lib')
}
```

In your **top-level gradle.build** file (so that you dont need it in all of your project build files)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.6'
    }
}
```

In your new **Project3-lib** project you have to apply the **android-library** plugin and not the android plugin

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```